# Save as using PHP or HTML (download a whole website)

Tags: php, javascript, html, web, download

I'm want to make website have a textbox and a save button. When you enter link there it saves the entire website (like the save page in google chrome). Is there a way to do this in php or html? If it is, is it possible to zip the site then download it? I can't think of anything.

I tried to use:

```
file_get_contents
```

but this only get the HTML code of the page. It doesn't matter if it saves the zip file on a server or database. And I can download it manually to my desktop.

I hope somebody can help.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when I put amazon.com in?

Comment: There you see how much work browsers actually do behind the scenes... :)

Comment: This might be a bit old school but you can just visit a site and press ctrl+s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most *nix systems have wget

```
wget -m http://www.example.com/
```

you can of course issue any server commands with php exec(),sys() etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function to perform this task in any server-side language that I know of. It is possible to program a script that can make copies of all a page's resources, but it is not easy or practical.

Comment: Fair enough. But for light usage it would be more practical to do it manually or using the browser's functions.

Comment: *That* I can agree with. It depends on what your goal is. :)